# Alljoyn Service behind a Linux firewall (iptables)

Tags: linux, tcp, firewall, iptables, alljoyn

I want to use the Alljoyn framework on an embedded linux device. Due to security reasons, it is necessary to configure a firewall for that device. This is done with iptables.

What I've done so far:
I tried to run the AboutService example on that device without firewall and then checked the TCPDump. As client, I used the IoT Explorer for AllJoyn (Windows 10), but AboutClient should work well, too. Checking TCPDump with wireshark, the ports for the announcement are clear, I have to open Ports **9955** (alljoyn-mcm) **9956** (alljoyn) and **5353** (MDNS?!?) for UDP. I solved that with following rules:

```
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 9955 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 9956 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT  -p udp --sport 9955 -j ACCEPT
```

With these rules, device is succesfully discovered in IoT explorer.

But when acessing the device (e.g. to get full about-data) TCP communication starts. And this is not on a certain port. The port seems to be random. NMap shows e.g. following ports, when (re)starting the AboutService.

- 46368/tcp open  unknown, or
- 52739/tcp open  unknown

How can I determine the port? How can I force Alljoyn framework to nail the TCP-Communication to a certain port or at least small port range, e.g. 41000-41100? Or is there any other way to configure the firewall so Alljoyn communication is not blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in another way:

Before starting my Alljoyn Service, I launched the `alljoyn-daemon` binary from the Alljoyn core lib. This routes the traffic over definable ports, by default over port **9955** (alljoyn-mcm).

With this setup I could configure following firewall rules and everything worked:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT  -p udp -m multiport --dports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT  -p udp -m multiport --sports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m multiport --dports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m multiport --sports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -m multiport --sports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 9955,9956,5353 -j ACCEPT
```

Hint: I suppose these are too much open ports but this is enough for me. With more investigation, the list can surely be reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the AllJoyn Framework, uses **UDP for discovery** and **TCP for direct communication**.

Wellkown (registered) ports are;

- Port Number 9956: IANA assigned UDP multicast port for AllJoyn
- Port Number 5353: IANA-assigned UDP multicast port for mDNS

When the devices discover each other, TCP communication starts on a random ephemeral port. This implementation is a target dependent code, you can check source codes of the target.